# Semisimple regular elements of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, lie-algebras

I want to prove that the semisimple regular elements of $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb{C})$ are the traceless elements with $n$ distinct eigenvalues.
Here, I take 'regular' to mean that $\dim Z_\mathfrak{g}(x) = \operatorname{rk} \mathfrak{g}$.

In one direction, $n$ distinct eigenvalues implies $x$ is semisimple and thus so too is $\operatorname{ad}_x$, and it also necessarily implies that the geometric multiplicity of 0 for $x$ is as small as possible, i.e. $x$ is regular.

In the other direction, I am lost.
The [wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_element_of_a_Lie_algebra#Basic_case) deals with regular elements of Lie groups, not Lie algebras, as indicated by the phrase

> However if there are equal eigenvalues, then the centralizer is the product of the **general linear groups** of the eigenspaces of $M$, and has strictly larger dimension, so that $M$ is not regular.

This is not true for the centraliser $Z_\mathfrak{g}(x) = \{ y \in \mathfrak{g} : \operatorname{ad}_x(y) = 0\}$: the centraliser has no relation (as far as I can tell) to the eigenspaces of $x$ itself.
Where am I going wrong?

Comment: What is the dimension of the space of $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$-matrices commuting with $\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & -2\end{pmatrix}$? In general, if there is a repeated eigenvalue, the centralizer is larger (it's an if and only if).

Comment: Ah I see. So $x \in \mathfrak{g}$ has a repeated eigenvalue if and only if it is not regular, i.e. regular iff no repeated eigenvalues. This makes sense, if you make it an answer I will mark it as solved, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A semisimple element $x$ in $\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ is of the form $x=G x' G^{-1}$ for some $G\in{\rm GL}_n(\mathbb C)$ and $x'=diag(\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n)$. The centralizer of $x$ is the set of matrices $y\in\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C)$ with $[x,y]=0$, i.e. writing $y=G y' G^{-1}$, $[x',y']=0$. The matrix entries of this equation are
$$
[x',y']_{ij}=y'_{ij}(\lambda_i-\lambda_j)=0.
$$
Thus the element is regular (meaning that the centralizer has dimension $n-1=rank(\mathfrak{sl}_n(\mathbb C))$) if and only if the $\lambda_i$'s are all distinct (otherwise the centralizer is larger).